# Fastest way to read a 32-bit integer from an offset in a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, java-17

Previous discussions on reading an integer from a byte array in Java, focus on the scenario where what you have is four bytes. I have a slightly different scenario:

- A fixed array of two billion bytes.
- Input: a random offset into that array. (Though hopefully sufficiently nonrandom to have a reasonably high cache hit rate.)
- This operation will happen frequently, such that it needs to run as fast as possible. The ideal would be if there is an idiom that the JIT compiler can recognize and compile into an unaligned load instruction, if the CPU supports such. (Every mainstream CPU pays for unaligned support in every memory access, even in the typical case when it's not used. Might as well take advantage of it, this one time when it would be useful.)

What's the the fastest way to perform this operation? Obviously I can just write the read-shift loop by hand, but is there a faster idiom? Or if it is to be done by hand, which variant generates the fastest code?

I'm on OpenJDK 17, if that matters.

Comment: fastest -> probably using JNI (not really an idiom, JIT compiler is no issue,  ... but we have full control), or/and [JEP 412: Foreign Function & Memory API](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/17-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8265033). `Buffer` can probably do the operation, but implementation detail if it is fastest way. Maybe the new [JEP 417: Vector API](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/18-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8269306) can help with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not can or wish to use internal classes, you can use a `VarHandle` to access this:

```
private static final VarHandle READ_ARRAY = MethodHandles.byteArrayViewVarHandle(int[].class, ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] arr = ...;
    
    int pos = ...; // pos is the index into the byte array, and may be unaligned.
    int result = (int) READ_ARRAY.get(arr, pos);


    System.out.println(result);
}
```

While this adds some indirection, ultimately it will call `Unsafe.unalignedAccess()` when supported.
And if you are using best practices (`VarHandle` in a `static final` field...), the JIT can usually inline everything down to `Unsafe.unalignedAccess()`.

Comment: The good old `ByteBuffer.wrap(arr).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).getInt(pos)` (since jdk1.4) may work as well. Both approaches end up at exactly the same `Unsafe.getIntUnaligned(…)` call.

Comment: Works well if you only have to do it with one array - otherwise you always have to wrap & order - not sure how much the JIT can rely on escape analysis to avoid that.

Comment: Both approaches get their maximum performance only when the JIT kicks in. I just wanted to point out that prior to the introduction of `VarHandle`, there still was a way to access this functionality which was not necessarily slower than messing around with `Unsafe` directly. Of course, affected programs should be benchmarked when it really matters, but I’m sure, a lot of people using `Unsafe` never verified the assumed necessity to use internal classes.